# Using if else statement in r

Tags: r

Am just new to R, just struggling to write a function to have a final table as shown in the final table. l have a data as seen below of two different fragments

```
chr  start  end  gene1  chr   start  end   gene2
chr1  2380  2370   0    chr1  3540   3589  0.03
chr2  4560  3458   0    chr2  4280   8790  0
chr2   4678  9846  1   chr2  4567   8648   1 
chr2  4321   5679  0.04 chr2  4621   5678  0.002
```

I want to write a function that loops through the data , where its sees 0 in each row in gene1 and gene1 it should report 0 in finalgene but where there is a fraction either gene1 and gene2, it should report 1 in the corresponding column and where it sees 1 or fractions in either column it should report 1 as shown in the final file below

```
chr  start  end  gene1  chr   start  end   gene2 finalgene
chr1  2380  2370   0    chr1  3540   3589  0.03.  1
chr2  4560  3458   0    chr2  4280   8790  0      0
chr2   4678  9846  1   chr2  4567   8648   1      1
chr2  4321   5679  0.04 chr2  4621   5678  0.002  1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can assign 1 if either `gene1` or `gene2` is not equal to 0 or 0 otherwise.

```
df$finalgene <- as.integer(df$gene1 != 0 | df$gene2 != 0)
```

Using `ifelse` you can write the above as :

```
df$finalgene <- ifelse(df$gene1 != 0 | df$gene2 != 0, 1, 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

We could also use `rowSums` from `base R`

```
df$finalgene <- +(rowSums(df[c('gene1', 'gene2')] != 0) > 0)
```